# How can I find customers with no orders in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine I have two tables:

customers(cust_id)
orders(order_id,cust_id)

How can I get all the customers who have no orders?

Example database:

```
customers
cust_id
1
2
3
4

orders
order_id customer_id
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        3

So what I want to retrieve is:

cust_id
4
```

Comment: This is not difficult, and can be accomplished via a `left join`. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Select cust_id where order_id >1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, a correlated subquery would perform best

```
select cust_id
from customers
where not exists (select * from orders
                  where orders.customer_id = customers.cust_id);
```

Another option is a LEFT join/NOT NULL combination

```
select c.cust_id
from customers c
left join orders o on o.customer_id = c.cust_id
where o.customer_id is null;
```

NOT IN is sometimes offered as a solution as well

```
select c.cust_id
from customers c
where c.cust_id NOT IN (select distinct customer_id from orders);
```

[Check here](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/) for an in-depth discussion of the various options and relative strengths.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.cust_id
FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN orders AS o
ON c.cust_id=o.customer_id
WHERE o.customer_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You select all rows from the customers table where the ID doesn't appear in the orders table

```
select * FROM customers where cust_id NOT IN 
   (select customer_id FROM orders)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Customers a
        LEFT JOIN Orders b
            ON a.Cust_ID = b.Customer_ID
WHERE   b.Customer_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from customers where cust_id not in (select distinct customer_id from orders)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.cust_id
from customers c
left join orders o on o.customer_id = c.cust_id
where o.customer_id is null;
```

try to avoid sub queries where possible - they can be an awful performance hit.